# MongoError unknown group operator

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDb Driver for NodeJS.

I am facing issues in using aggregation. 
The error is

> {"name":"MongoError","message":"unknown group operator
>   '_id'","ok":0,"errmsg":"unknown group operator '_id'","code":15952}

for the below script :

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err) 
      {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
        return;
      }
    var collName = "order";
    var whereParas = {};
    var groupParas = {"_id":null,total:{$sum:"$Value"}};
    var havingParas = {};

            db.collection(collName).aggregate(
            [
            { $match: whereParas },
            {
              $group: { groupParas}
            },
            { $match: havingParas }
        ]).toArray(function (err,result) {
            console.log("err");
            console.log(err);
            console.log("result");
            console.log(result);

            });
});
```

The data used is [image]

Desired Output is Sum of Values.

In sql, I would have written :

```
Select Sum(Value) From order
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group pipeline should be `{ $group: groupParas }` instead of `{ $group: { groupParas } }` hence the error you are getting as Mongo is trying to interpret the nested document win the object as the `_id` group operator.