# PHP MongoDB Driver Command - Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException: exception: unknown group operator

Tags: php, mongodb

I've the following php mongo code in php7 and it failed with the following error PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException: exception: unknown group operator 'token'. I'm not sure what's the issue. And the stack trace have it on executeCommand. Any idea what's the issue?

```
$mongoClient = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://'.$mongo_server_address, $mongo_options);
$cmd = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(
    [
        'aggregate' => 'mycollection',
        'pipeline' => [
            ['$group' => [
                'key' => ["token" => 1],
                'reduce' => new \MongoDB\BSON\Javascript("function( curr, result ) { result.count++; }"),
                'cond' => [
                    'token' => ['$ne' => NULL],
                    'token' => ['$exists' => true, '$not' => ['$size' => 0]],
                    'createdAt' => ['$gte' => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 days')) . ' 00:00:00')), '$lte' => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00'))]
                ],
                'initial' => ["count" => 0]
            ]]
        ],
        'cursor' => new stdClass()
    ]
 );
 $rows = $mongoClient->executeCommand($mongo_table_name, $cmd);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525879/mongoerror-unknown-group-operator

Comment: It's not duplicate. That one is node.js and my question is for php